# Why zoneminder monitor function utilizing camera constantly even when no one is monitoring

Tags: function, stream, monitor, alwayson, zoneminder

My IP camera has a LED which blink when someone is streaming from it. When I add the camera to zoneminder as monitor function, the LED keeps blinking constantly meaning zoneminder is streaming from it. It also keep blinking even when nobody is using it. I mean no one is using web site to watch the camera nor anybody is using any API to utilize it. The problem is, it's using network bandwidth constantly. It would make sense if it was on mocap or record function but monitor function doesn't need to stream unless someone is watching it. Wouldn't it be better to only read from camera when somebody is using it (app or website)? Is there any option that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Zoneminder convert/relay any stream from mjpeg or h264 to jpg images, so need consume the stream all the time. If you really want close the daemon, disable the camera, and so on.